# An Example of Negatively Correlated Programs

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I'm looking to construct 2 negatively correlated functions which means that for example

```c
void program()
{
   f1(x);
   f2(x);
}
```

Both **f1** and **f2** functions are dependent to input *x* and I want that when the execution time of **f1** is increasing, **f2** should decrease and vice versa.

I'm thinking the parameter *x* as a randomly generated array and **f1** as a sorting algorithm. However, i can not think of an example for **f2**.

Could anyone give me an example for such function couples ?

**Edit 1:** Actually I found an example for both **f1** and **f2** for my needs. Initially I forgot to mention that those functions need to be realistic, which means that I'm not looking a simple calling of **sleep()** in each function. I also wrote the **x** in order to represent some "abstract" input, it can be anything in reality.

I build the **f1** and **f2** respectively as follows:

```c
void f1(x)
{
   //sort first x elements of an array
}

void f2(x)
{
   //sort last MAXSIZE - x elements of an array
}
```

This way If I randomly create an array and an **x** in each trial, **f1** and **f2** would execute perfectly negatively correlated and **f1** and **f2** become realistic programs. Below is the correlation plot of the execution times of f1 and f2 respectively.

[image: Negative correlated functions]

Comment: Given an integer input, one counts up to `INT_MAX`, one counts down to `INT_MIN`.

Comment: Or do literally any other task `x` times in `f1` and `N-x` times in `f2`...

Comment: `void program { /* ... */ }` is ill-formed. Do you mean `void program()`?

Comment: If f1() is an O(nlogn) sorting process this would require f2() to be an O(1/(nlogn)) process. Such a process would get easier as the size of the input increases. I have never heard of such an algorithm.

Comment: @MaxLanghof and Blaze thank you both. I actually found a suitable fit for my needs based on your suggestions which I added to the question.

Comment: @LeventBekdemir If you found an answer and want to share it, don't add it to the question. Please post it as an answer! Don't worry, that's what they're for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If f1() is an O(nlogn) sorting process this would require f2() to be an O(1/(nlogn)) process. Such a process would get easier as the size of the input increases. I have never heard of such an algorithm (not saying such doesn't exist).

If there was some natural upper bound to the total execution time f2() could just wait a period of time = UPPER_BOUND - estimate of the execution time of f1(). If f1() has execution time knlogn for some k, then

```
void f2(x)
{
sleep (UPPER_BOUND - k * size(x) * log(size(x)));
}
```

would seem to work.

The case where f1() and f2() are not independent programs but work on some program together is different. Here I am thinking of a problem such as AI search which can either progress in a forward chaining manner or in a backwards chaining manner.

If f1() is an attempts to reach a goal node by forward chaining https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_chaining and f2() is an attempt to ground a goal node in the axiom set by backwards chaining https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_chaining so that together f1() and f2() attempt to solve a the search then one may *hope* that f1() and f2() have the behaviour desired.

If f1() and f2() operate in parallel then it is likely that if the problem is easy for f1() it will be hard for f2() and vice versa as the search difficulty will not be symmetric.

This is similar to a bidirectional search problems. In fact on reflection this is a more question problem than it seems at first sight as it could generate insights into the behaviour of a whole class of bidirectional search problems.

Bidirectional search is motivated by the idea that f1() and f2() will somehow 'meet in the middle' (See Bratko  https://slideplayer.com/slide/3351420/) which implies communication between them

[image]

In the case you describe I would argue that f1() and f2() cannot at the sime communicate and yet be different programs, but the phenomenon you seek would arise if one direction has a branching factor very different to the other but for which the cheapest direction is unknown at the outset.

Comment: I edited my question. Actually I'm not looking for a simple sleep calling function, rather I'm looking for some realistic programs. Thats why I mentioned sorting etc.. However, I think I found a solution, thanks anyway

Comment: Updated to include a generalisation of the new example provided in your question.